# Average clustering coefficient of a network (igraph)

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I want to calculate the average clustering coefficient of a graph (from `igraph` package). However, I am not sure which approach I should follow.

```
library(igraph)
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(10000, 10000, type = "gnm")

# Global clustering coefficient
transitivity(graph)
# Average clustering coefficient
transitivity(graph, type = "average")
# The same as above
mean(transitivity(graph, type = "local"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

I would be grateful for some guidance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `transitivity(graph)` computes a global clustering coefficient (transitivity):

> This is simply the ratio of the triangles and the connected triples in
>   the graph. For directed graph the direction of the edges is ignored.

Meanwhile, `transitivity(graph, type = "average")` being an average of `transitivity(graph, type = "local")` first computes the local clustering coefficients and then averages them:

> The local transitivity of an undirected graph, this is calculated for
>   each vertex given in the vids argument. The local transitivity of a
>   vertex is the ratio of the triangles connected to the vertex and the
>   triples centered on the vertex. For directed graph the direction of
>   the edges is ignored.

See, e.g., `?transitivity` and [Clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient).

So firstly both of them are valid measures and the choice should depend on your purposes. The difference between them is quite clear (see the wikipedia page):

> It is worth noting that this metric places more weight on the low
>   degree nodes, while the transitivity ratio places more weight on the
>   high degree nodes. In fact, a weighted average where each local
>   clustering score is weighted by k_i(k_i-1) is identical to the global clustering
>   coefficient

where k_i is the number of vertex *i* neighbours. Hence, perhaps using both of them would be quite fair too.

Answer (score 2):

@Julius Vainora answered it. Additional note for those that are trying to look for some answers for what does *type = "average"* do since igraph documentation doesn't say anything about it:

```
transitivity(graph, type = "average")
```

is the same as

```
transitivity(graph, type = "localaverage")
```

is the same as

```
transitivity(graph, type = "localaverageundirected")
```

is the same as

```
mean(transitivity(graph, type = "local"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
transitivity(g, type="local")
```

How about the order of the output vector?
Is it same as the order of:

```
degree(g, mode="all")
```

The degree vector has indexs but clustering coefficient not